# SQL - Command to get Id's with unique flags from multiple flags

Tags: sql, select

```
ID  Risk_1  Risk_2  Risk_3  Risk_4
XYZ Yes             Yes     Yes
ABC Yes
PQR Yes     Yes
```

As you can see from the above table There are IDs that have multiple risks associated with them. I want to get an output of IDs where only one risk is associated with them.

In the case above I want all IDs which have only risk_1 so the result should be ABC.

How can I get this done using SQL?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `Risks` are *nullable*.

```
SELECT  ID
FROM    tableName
WHERE   CASE WHEN Risk_1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN Risk_2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN Risk_3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN Risk_4 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5c6e/2)

if however they are empty string,

```
SELECT  ID
FROM    tableName
WHERE   CASE WHEN Risk_1 <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN Risk_2 <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN Risk_3 <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN Risk_4 <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33729/1)

Answer (score 0):

That will work with NULLs, empty strings, or values other than Yes (e.g. No)

```
SELECT ID
  FROM Table1
  WHERE COALESCE(Risk_1, 'No') = 'Yes'  AND
        COALESCE(Risk_2, 'No') <> 'Yes' AND
        COALESCE(Risk_3, 'No') <> 'Yes' AND
        COALESCE(Risk_4, 'No') <> 'Yes'
```

**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5c6e/8)**

Answer (score 0):

If you altered your schema so your table had columns `ID` and `risk_type` with a row for each risk type, you could have a query like this:

```
SELECT ID
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7ac7a/2)

re-edit: modified to no longer specify which one risk type they have

Answer (score 0):

If the value of risks are only `'Yes'` then below query will work

```
select ID from table where risk1||risk2||risk3||risk4='Yes'
```

If the value of risks are only `'Yes'` and the empty risks have `spaces` instead of nulls then below query will work

```
select ID from table where replace(risk1||risk2||risk3||risk4,' ','')='Yes'
```